# Flash - time from press

Tags: flash, time, drag-and-drop, detect

I am working on a little project, what's goal is a working widget system in Flash - by creating a separate class, and loading Flash movies into this, then dragging them around the screen.

I ran into a little problem when I was writing the dragging code:
I can not found any code what can easily get the time from the function call. To be more precise, I want the container only draggable after 2 seconds of continuous press, and that's what I am trying to detect.

Is there any easy solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
Timer pressTimer = new Timer(2000);
pressTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,onMouseUp);
function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
  pressTimer.start();
}
function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
  pressTimer.reset();
}
function onTimer(e:TimerEvent):void {
  pressTimer.reset();
  //do the dragging and stuff.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it did not work. Maybe it is a problem I am trying to do it in Flash Lite 2?

Comment: First of all, it won't even compile. Some problems with the first presstime.addEventListener, and it should not active on mouse down, but on press and release (for touch screens).